# Change the domain and the user name from cmd or powershell with only 1 rebooting

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, reboot, domain

I would like to change the user name and the domain without the need of rebooting between the 2 steps.
When I use Windows 10 GUI (System propertes...) for that, it can be done, and the reboot is needed only in the end of all procedures.
But when I try to do the same with Windows commands, it requires 1 restart when changing the name, then another when adding to domain. If I run both then restart, only the name changes.

Could anybody suggest, how to do that with only restarting in the end?

Comment: You mean a Local Username? Can you please show the code you use so far

Comment: You need to be more clear. Windows does not require a reboot on username changes. It does need a reboot or computer name or domain name change or the combination of the two. Ditton on what @SimonS said. There should be no reason for a reboot on a computer name and then another on a domain name change, as those area single step, not two. There are many examples all over the web showing how to do this in PowerShell.  SU rules: [How to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you please provide which command you use to change the user name and add domain?

Comment: I think you're talking about changing the computer name and then after the computer name is changed to something different to then join it to the domain. You aren't really changing any usernames, correct? It is the computer name you are changing? It sounds like it allows you to change the computer name and NOT restart and then turn around and join it to the domain, and you just restart once and everything is as you need it, correct? Supply your post with the PowerShell logic you are using to perform these changes.

Comment: Maybe you're talking about the script running under a different user profile?  If so, I don't think PS-Credential needs a new session, or reboot.